# How to Consume SOAP WSDL Using Vertx 3

Tags: vert.x, vertx-httpclient

i have a project in vertx.3, i wanna to consuming a SOAP service.
is there a lib in vertx that allow me to do that? 
i do a lot of search and i get anything.

please some one can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no SOAP module in the Vert.x stack. That being said, you can craft SOAP messages in XML yourself, also by reading the WSDL descriptor if any.

For sure this is not an ideal solution, but it is doable.

Another option is to use the [Vert.x Camel Bridge](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-camel-bridge/java/) and have Camel / SOAP do the endpoint adaptation for you.